# MYSQL double WHERE clause not working with = and AND

Tags: mysql

I have a query, generated by DataMapper (an ORM for CodeIgniter) that is returning results on one server, but not on another.

Both databases are exactly the same. The query works on servers with MYSQL versions 5.1.41, 5.1.63 and 5.5.20, and fails on 5.1.52.

The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `clients`.`id`
FROM (`clients`)

LEFT OUTER JOIN `clients_locations`
    clients_locations ON `clients`.`id` = `clients_locations`.`client_id`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations`
    locations ON `locations`.`id` = `clients_locations`.`location_id`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `reports`
    location_reports ON `locations`.`id` = `location_reports`.`location_id`

WHERE
    `location_reports`.`id` =  1
AND 
    `clients`.`id` =  2
```

I've done some testing, and I've found the following things out:

> If you just have 1 WHERE clause, it returns results.
>   If you change *any* of the operators to LIKE, != etc, it returns results
>   If you change the AND to an OR, it returns the results.

Similar queries are used throughout the site, so I don't know why it is this one that's failing. For instance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `clients`.`id`
FROM (`clients`)

LEFT OUTER JOIN `clients_locations`
    clients_locations ON `clients`.`id` = `clients_locations`.`client_id`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations`
    locations ON `locations`.`id` = `clients_locations`.`location_id`

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `locations_questionnaires` location_locations_questionnaires 
ON 
    `locations`.`id` = `location_locations_questionnaires`.`location_id`

WHERE
    `location_locations_questionnaires`.`questionnaire_id` =  3
AND 
     `clients`.`id` =  2
```

returns the correct results on all the servers listed above.

Has anyone seen this before?

To clarify:

**I can't edit the SQL, as it's produced by an ORM.**

**Both datasets are EXACTLY the same.**

**The issue is why the query doesn't return any results on one server, when it does on the other.**

**UPDATE**: I've just upgraded the server to 5.1.61, and the query runs fine. So looks like it's a bug in 5.1.52.

Comment: If you run it WITHOUT the `AND clients.id=2` will 2 be in the resultset?

Comment: Yeah, without the AND clients.id=2 in the query, I get back three results. '2' is one of them.

Comment: That seems to make it clear: Try `WHERE (location_locations_questionnaires.questionnaire_id=3 OR location_locations_questionnaires.questionnaire_id IS NULL)
AND clients.id=2`

Comment: That works (when I apply it to the top failing query). Why would it be returning NULL though, and only on this query? The data is all there and linked up.

Comment: Seems like there is (at least) one rowset, where `location_locations_questionnaires.questionnaire_id=3` is true for one half and `clients.id=2` is true for the other half. By allowing the NULL you recouple those two.

Comment: OK, but then why does the query work on one server but not the other, when they have exactly the same data?

Comment: Are you sure they have? Run mysqldump on both and `diff` the output. (Assuming they are not too big)

Comment: Positive, all tests were from a fresh copy of the failing database (it's only small). See the latest addition to the question :)

Answer (score 2):

The WHERE condition on an outer joined table, e.g.

```
WHERE location_reports.id =  1
```

effectively turns the outer join into an inner join. If you move that condition into the JOIN condition, it works correctly (as you have already noticed).

The reason is that the WHERE condition is applied *after* the JOINs, as the outer joined rows do not have a value for `location_reports.id` the condition is false for them and they are removed from the result.

Comment: I think I follow you, but then why does it work for other tables, and on other servers, just not this one?

Comment: @Toddish: I guess different data. Maybe the outer join is not needed on the other servers (or tables) because all rows from the "left" table match to one (or more) in the "right" table.

Comment: The data is exactly the same; I exported the data from the failing database and imported it into the one that works. The only difference is the MYSQL version.

Comment: @Toddish: then I can only assume a MySQL bug. Sorry, don't know anything else. I'm seldomly forced to work with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `clients`.`id`
FROM (`clients`)

LEFT OUTER JOIN `clients_locations`
    clients_locations ON `clients`.`id` = `clients_locations`.`client_id`
    AND `clients`.`id` =  2

LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations`
    locations ON `locations`.`id` = `clients_locations`.`location_id`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `reports`
    location_reports ON `locations`.`id` = `location_reports`.`location_id`
    AND `location_reports`.`id` =  1
```

Comment: That sort of works, but brings back all the client IDs, not the specified one. I should have made it clearer at the top as well, I can't edit the SQL as it's generated by the ORM.